# How does the stack overflow captcha work, and can it be replicated in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While I'm not sure on the exactitudes, the logic when submitting a question appears to be something like this:

```
      |
 user submits question form  <-------
      |                             | 
      V                             |
=============================       |
| Are the attributes valid? | ----> NO 
=============================
      |
     YES  
      |
      V
===============================================================
| Has user submitted more than 4 forms in the last 5 minutes? | --NO---| 
===============================================================        |
     |                                                                 |
    YES                                                                |
     |                                                                 |
  redirect them to recaptcha form                                      |
     |                                                                 |
     V                                                                 V
============================                    ************************************
|  Captcha form incorrect? | -- NO ---------->  *   save the form as a record      *
============================                    *     and redirect user to see it  *
     |              ^                           ************************************
    YES             |
     |              NO
     V              |
==================================================
|  Have they been redirected to the captcha form | 
|    more than 5 times in the last minute?       |
==================================================
     |
    YES
     |
     V
*******************
* TEMPORARY BLOCK *
*******************
```

There's probably similar logic behind the user sign up process. I really like it, because it only serves a captcha when a user is acting suspiciously, rather than hitting everyone with a captcha, which appears to be the only way to implement a captcha with rails.

Google's recaptcha gem seems to add a recaptcha field to **every single one of your forms** and then validate it before the instance is saved. I don't like this because it's wasting people's time with a captcha when there is no need.

So I tried to make my own logic captcha that simply asks a slightly silly question and checks the user's answer against an array of possible answers. I thought it would be simple enough, but it turns out to be impossible with Rails, or at least very work around-y.

Let's say I have a project written in rails where users can post questions like a miniture stack overflow. Here are the problems I encounter when trying to create an intermittent recaptcha like what's found on SO:

- **Has user submitted more than 4 forms in the last 5 minutes?**

I can manage that okay. I have a before hook in my application controller that means whenever a create action is triggered, the time at which is it took place is appended to an array of unix timestamps in the `session` hash, session[:interactions]. The same action then sees if there are twenty time stamps and if so, it iterates though each of them, finds out the average time between each interaction, and if the average time is below a certain amount then I redirect them to a recaptcha form.

Before the redirect, I create a new, empty answer instance and a question instance that contains a question, which be both used in the recaptcha view.

**Here's where stuff starts to get hacky.** In order to remember what question we asked the user (as so to check the question's answers), I need to save the id in the session hash, `session[:question_id]`. In order to conserve the data entered into the question form, I need to save the `question_params` hash inside the session hash, session[:attempt]. I don't know, is this a done thing?

- **Captcha form incorrect?**

I redirect them towards a view that holds the captcha form, `views/application/recaptcha.html.erb`. In this view, the question is displayed, below which is a form. The form submits its data to another method,`application#human?`, via a post route. Inside the `human?` I can find the question's possible answers via the id inside `session[:question_id]`.

But then what? This is where I gave up and posted the question. I mean it's just getting crazy. If the user submitted the right answer then can I just run `session[:attempt].save`? Feels pretty unorthodox. And while maybe I could redirect to the question's show view with `redirect_to session[:attempt]`, I don't feel like I'm going the right way about it. What if the question was part of a nested URL structure, maybe it has to be found at `users/jimmy/categories/important/questions/23` how could the `human?` method know to redirect to that? How could it then redirect to other instances when they've been saved, like when a new user has passed the recaptcha and just been saved?

It's just impossible to do with rails, but it seems like such basic behaviour when using Stack Overflow:

### **"If you're using a bit heavily, up comes a recaptcha on your next request. If you pass, you can carry on."**

What a can of worms exists in those two sentences. It seems utterly impossible to do that with Rails.

Could someone help me out? Thanks

Comment: Open ended, well worded question. You people are damn annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add an attribute `human_confirmed` to your Post/Question model ?

When the user first submits his question, the question is saved in the database with the `human_confirmed` attribute to `false`. The question won't be displayed until it's true.

Validating the captcha sets that attribute to true.

If you save those in database, you can then also easily count how many questions were submitted.

Lastly, you can run a script every night for instance that deletes from the database every question that wasn't validated in 24 hours.

Comment: It's more to protect against DDoS/Spam rather than a measure to avoid having my database filled with superfluous data..

Comment: Neither of those solutions will help you against DDoS, but this will protect you against Spam. A sql request deleting questions unanswered is also pretty lightweight and can be run more often than "every night".